# Expo only working on web and fails on Android with multiple issues

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

My project is mainly based on this [boilerplate](https://github.com/howtographql/react-apollo). To not get into trouble with the deployments later on, I'm using `expo`.

Now I'm just wondering why the deployment to Android is not working. When I deploy it to web it works great without any trouble. But doing [image: expo android deploy] gives me [image: expo android log] and this on the Android Emulator:

[image: android emulator error]

But the project structure is clean and that `index.css` is working properly

[image: project structure]

What is the difference between a `Run in web` and `Run on android`?

Also when I just remove that index.css for testing. Web still works but without styles. But on Android I now get another error on my used `localstorage`.

I know there is a difference between `react-native` and `react-web`. But I was thinking that `expo` is able to handle this. Maybe I was expecting too much from `expo`? So am I wrong with that and all is fine. And all I have to do is making it work on Android, like fixing the `index.css` issue and the `localstorage`? Or is there a smarter way to get my obviously `react-web` application to work on my Android device?

Comment: do you have index.css file in assets folder?

Comment: Sure and everything else like the localstorage is working, but only in Web expo deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `react-native` and `react-native-web` are very different.

- `react-native` - using native UI controls and have full access to the native platform
- `react-native-web` - brings the platform-agnostic Components and APIs of React Native to the Web

While it is possible to use `react-native-web` for web and native like Android, it is not recommended. You always have to do workarounds like with the `localstorage`.

It is better to completely **switch to `react-native`** and **rewrite all the code** to be working in the native way. Like instead of using an `index.css` you now have to create the `Stylesheet` in the code directly.

---

But for the case someone really wants to use the boilerplate from the question you need to refactor the code. This is described [here](https://codersera.com/blog/react-native-web-tutorials-your-first-hybrid-app/).
But in short you need a helper `App.js` like this one:

```
// /App.js
import React from 'react';
import HybridApp from './src/App';
const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <HybridApp />
  );
}
export default App;
```